# Find unique values that do not exist in multiple columns and tables

Tags: mysql, sql

A misconfigured manual import imported our entire AD into our help desk user database, creating a bunch of extraneous/duplicate accounts. Of course, no backup to restore from.

To facilitate the cleanup, I want to run a query that will find users not currently linked to any current or archived tickets. I have three tables, `USER`, `HD_TICKET`, and `HD_ARCHIVE_TICKET`. I want to compare the `ID` field in `USER` to the `OWNER_ID` and `SUBMITTER_ID` fields in the other two tables, returning the only the values in `USER.ID` that do not exist in any of the other four columns.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: @JakeGould: Why do you think that?

Comment: To my understanding, the question doesn't deserve a down vote.

Comment: What's supposed to happen if a user hasn't submitted any tickets/doesn't own any tickets?  Are you just blanket deleting everybody this first query returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a left join for each relationship where the right table id is null:

```
select user.*
from user
left join hd_ticket on user.id = hd_ticket.owner_id
left join hd_ticket as hd_ticket2 on user.id = hd_ticket2.submitter_id
left join hd_archive_ticket on user.id = hd_archive_ticket.owner_id
left join hd_archive_ticket as hd_archive_ticket2 on user.id = hd_archive_ticket2.submitter_id
where hd_ticket.owner_id is null
and hd_ticket2.submitter_id is null
and hd_archive_ticket.owner_id is null
and hd_archive_ticket2.submitter_id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
SELECT  id
FROM    user
WHERE   id NOT IN
(
    SELECT  owner_id
    FROM    hd_ticket
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  submitter_id
    FROM    hd_ticket
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  owner_id
    FROM    hd_archive_ticket
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  submitter_id
    FROM    hd_archive_ticket
)
```

Comment: Functional, but extremely slow as I am attempting to sort through thousands of records.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you situation I would do this:

```
SELECT a.id FROM user a, hd_ticket b, hd_archive_ticket c WHERE a.id != b.id AND a.id != c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to try something like below. Inner query where I am doing Inner join with other 2 tables, will return only those user id which exist in all 3 tables. Then in your outer query I am just filtering out those ID's returned by inner query; since your goal is to get only those USER ID which is not present in other tables.

```
select ID 
FROM USER
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
select u.ID
from user u
inner join HD_TICKET h on u.ID = h.OWNER_ID
inner join HD_ARCHIVE_TICKET ha on u.ID = ha.SUBMITTER_ID
)
```